# Action Created - automatically setting a created user status to accepted - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new to rails and your advise will much appreciated

> aim: i am trying to set the status of users who are admins to "accepted"
>   when created

- the table `users` in the schema has the columns `status` & `category_role_id`
- `category_role_id 1` are `admins` and `category_role_id 2` are `primary admins`
- currently when a user is created (signs up for an account) their status is automatically set to `nil`

can one kindly advise me how i can set the status of a created user who is an admin to "accepted" (so when they create an account/signup their `status` would state `"accepted"` rather than `nil`)

> schema

```
  create_table "userrs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "category_role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "category_roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

> models

```
user.rb
User belongs_to :category_role

category_role.rb
CategoryRole has_many :users
```

> users_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(setting_user_path(current_userr), notice: 'User was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

> i have no idea how to do this - i tried the below, but i believe it is
>   wrong

```
  def create
    @userr = Userr.new(userr_params)
    if @user.category_role_id == nil
      @user.category_role_id == 1
      @user.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(setting_usrr_path(current_user), notice: 'User was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a callback to `User` model. Separately, it looks like your `users` table is misspelled in your migration.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :set_admin_as_accepted

  def admin?
     [1,2].include?(category_role_id)
  end

  def set_admin_as_accepted
    self.status = 'accepted' if admin?
  end

end
```